# How to create seed_data.txt for use in the Sel_DataGen() function in the GenEpiSim Package?

Tags: r

I am very new to R and programming for biostatistical research. I am attempting to use the `Sel_DataGen()` function in the `{GenEpiSim}` package. In order to run the main function in the package, I need to create "a file containing seeds for each replicate in the working directory. This file is provided by the user and named 'seed_data.txt.'"

I created the file "seed_data.txt" within my working directory, but have not figured out how to "put seeds" in it. Running the function as is results in this response:

```
Error in read.table("seed_data.txt", header = F) : 
  no lines available in input
```

I realize that this means that the file is empty. How can I set seeds within this folder? Additionally, does this mean that I'll have to create a new seed file each time I run the function?

Thank you, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What package and function are you trying to use here?

Comment: Understanding the utility of a random seed so that stochastic processes can be reproduced when needed ... I don't know where that "R notes" is referenced, nor how it intends you to fill that. All that said, if there's a random process being replicated, start the script with `seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, size=1); set.seed(seed)` and store (as needed) the value stored in `seed` for that replication.

Comment: @the-mad-statter the package is GenEpiSim (from GitHub), function is "Sel_DataGen"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use `GenEpiSim::Sel_DataGen()` then the example 'seed_data.txt' in the package contains 5 digit numbers with the following characteristics:

```r
example_seeds <- readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SmaragdaT/GenEpi/master/GenEpiSim/seed_data.txt")

summary(as.numeric(example_seeds))
#>    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#>   10019   12586   15316   15140   17929   19966

hist(as.numeric(example_seeds))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This appears to be a rather uniform distribution ranging from 10,000 to 20,000.

Therefore, the following should generate your required file:

```
nReps <- 10 # set to whatever your nReps truly are
r_seeds <- runif(nReps, 10000, 20000)
i_seeds <- round(r_seeds)
writeLines(as.character(i_seeds), "seed_data.txt")
```

Note that replicating the distributional characteristics of the example seeds is not necessary as any nReps number of integers would suffice.

If you wish to have reproducible results, you would only create this file once.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to create a text file with as many seeds as replicates `nReps`, as required.
The `sample` instruction is borrowed from [r2evans' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77765584/how-do-i-create-a-file-containing-seeds-for-each-replicate-in-order-to-run-the-m/77765737#comment137098294_77765584)

```
nReps <- 5L
sample(.Machine$integer.max, size = nReps) |>
  as.character() |>
  writeLines(con = "seed_data.txt")
```